# Why did I start getting 'max': identifier not found error in C++?

Tags: c++

I've recently started getting this error. This part of the code was working fine but suddenly stopped working after some bigger changes to other (mostly unrelated) parts of the project.

I have both `windows.h` and `stdlb.h` included and have also tried manually definig it, but am still gettin an error. Note that <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>right click</kbd> on `max()` finds 3 matches in visual studio (my define, stdlib and minwindef) but doesn't jump to one.

`#define max(a, b)  (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))`

My code looks like this

```
#define MYMAX(a, b) max(a, b)
...
return MYMAX(indexa, indexb);
...
```

Using `std::max(indexa, indexb)` fixes the issue, but would still like to know why the previous code suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Just `#include <algorithm>` and use `std::max`. I will never understand everyone's obsession with obfuscating their code with macros.

Comment: Your definition (as shown) - `#define MYMAX max(a, b)` doesn't give the `MYMAX` macro any arguments, so the 'call' to it in `return MYMAX(indexa, indexb);` is invalid.

Answer (score 5):

`Windows.h` contains a `#ifndef NOMINMAX` which prevents `<algorithm>` from breaking on `std::max`.

Using a macro is bad enough, but `max` is lowercase. The very strong consensus is that any macro should be all upper case, e.g. `MAX`. Microsoft tries to avoid breaking existing code, so they haven't yet removed `max` from `windows.h` despite the problems it gives. But you can and should remove it yourself. A common approach is `#define NOMINMAX` in `stdafx.h` or `pch.h` prior to `#include <windows.h>`, which fixes it for all source files that use the precompiled header. But you can also use a `.vcxproj` or `.props` file for this.

Presumably someone in your team recently added this definition somewhere. The only question should be, why only now?

Comment: I've run into this for years (specifically using `numeric_limits<T>::max()`), and never knew about `NOMINMAX` (would always just do `#undef max`), thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because you didn't define `max`.

> would still like to know why previous code suddenly stopped working.

You are asking the wrong question. You should be asking "Why did the code previously work?". Without a MCVE I cannot answer for certain, but answers may range from "you used to define it" to "the name was found with using declaration or ADL" or "some header that you include used to define it".

---

P.S. I recommend not using a macro such as this.